# How to fix TIMESTAMPS_MILLIS to TIMESTAMP_SECONDS bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need some help with big query.

I have a cloud function that receives a message from pub/sub and writes into my table, the problem is I've made a mistake and used `TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(@hitTS)` when `hitTS` has sent in `SECONDS`. I should use `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(@hitTS)`

How my entries look like:

```
|            hitTS            |
-------------------------------
|"1970-01-19 22:44:46.921 UTC"|
|"1970-01-19 22:51:57.842 UTC"|
|"1970-01-19 22:52:27.482 UTC"|
|"1970-01-19 22:43:15.541 UTC"|
```

with the following query I can get the `TIMESTAMP`

```sql
SELECT
 hitTS,  UNIX_MILLIS(hitTS) as MILLI
FROM
  `my.table`
WHERE
  DATE(hitTS) < "1971-01-01"
```

RESULT:

```
|            hitTS            ||    MILLIS    |
-----------------------------------------------
|"1970-01-19 22:44:46.921 UTC"|   1637086921  |
|"1970-01-19 22:51:57.842 UTC"|   1637517842  |
|"1970-01-19 22:52:27.482 UTC"|   1637547482  |
|"1970-01-19 22:43:15.541 UTC"|   1636995541  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I figured that if I take the `MILLIS` field and add `000` to the end it seems I get the correct Date...

It's possible to create a query here I update the hole table using the the above logic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you need to multiply x 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found what to do to get the dates fixed (by adding `000`) you can try this approach to update your values;

```
UPDATE `my.table`
SET hitTS=TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST(CONCAT(CAST(UNIX_MILLIS(hitTS) AS STRING),'000') AS INT64))
WHERE
  DATE(hitTS) < "1971-01-01"
```

I revised the following documentation for this solution: [timestamp_functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions) and [string_functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions)